# Implementing Feeds using Three20 Drag to Refresh; Does not update

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm implementing a Feed Project basically using Three20 Twitter sample as my reference but using my own website's api to get XML response..

I have already functions that will allow myself to post, delete feeds, but when I drag to refresh the TTTableViewController, it does not update the data in the table, what it does is, it goes back to the state where I first loaded the table.

The data from the first XML response is what I will always get.

```
- (void)load:(TTURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy more:(BOOL)more {
if (!self.isLoading && TTIsStringWithAnyText(_apiKey) && TTIsStringWithAnyText(_sessionKey)) {
    if(more) {
        _pageNumber++;
    }
    else {
        _pageNumber = 1;
        _finished = NO;
        [_feeds removeAllObjects];
    }

    NSString* url = @"api.mySiteHereWithParameters.com"
    TTURLRequest* request = [TTURLRequest requestWithURL: url delegate: self];

    request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy | TTURLRequestCachePolicyEtag;
    request.cacheExpirationAge = TT_CACHE_EXPIRATION_AGE_NEVER;

    TTURLXMLResponse* response = [[TTURLXMLResponse alloc] init];
    response.isRssFeed = YES;
    request.response = response;
    TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(response);

    [request send];
}
```

}

Basically when I drag and refresh, this is called and it goes back down to TTListDatasource and updates the table view, everything else is handled with three20 framework

Comment: When are you reloading the uitableview?

Comment: I want to reload it after the Drag to refresh, but the XML response i get is the same with what I get it from the first time

Comment: Yeah but what is your data source? Are you updating it when you get the response?

Comment: I'm using TTListDataSource, and yes I'm updating it also

Comment: Post the code where you update the data source and where you call to update the table view.

Comment: I suspect that [_feeds removeAllObjects] is being called here. If feeds is your data source then check your code logic again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a cache issue. I see you're using etags to cache. Does your server support that? It has to be enabled and configured on the server side.

try to use the standard caching:

```
request.cachePolicy = cachePolicy;
request.cacheExpirationAge = TT_DEFAULT_CACHE_EXPIRATION_AGE;
```

Comment: thanks man, i really didn't pay a lot of attention here, thank you thank you